# I have a file.I need to use grep to print all the lines whose quantity is between 100-500

Tags: linux

In example below, quantity is the field with the '38' tag, e.g. 38=842 on the first line.

```
Order:167342,9=205|21=1|553=2453|49=11342|56=MBT|10=085|55=/GCQ3|1=30532|114=Y|40=1|35=D|54=|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|34=388|11=|38=842|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|59=0|100=MBTX|43=Y|8=FIX.4.4|

Order:544291,52=20130624-09:45:02.046|59=0|100=MBTX|43=Y|8=FIX.4.4|54=|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|40=1|35=D|34=388|11=|38=952|56=MBT|1=30532|114=Y|10=085|55=/GCQ3|9=205|21=1|553=2453|49=11342|

Order:916070,35=D|40=1|54=|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|38=234|34=388|11=|59=0|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|8=FIX.4.4|100=MBTX|43=Y|9=205|553=2453|49=11342|21=1|56=MBT|55=/GCQ3|10=085|1=30532|114=Y|

Order:332907,9=205|49=11342|553=2453|21=1|56=MBT|114=Y|1=30532|55=/GCQ3|10=085|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|54=|35=D|40=1|38=26|11=|34=388|59=0|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|8=FIX.4.4|43=Y|100=MBTX|

Order:385327,38=190|34=388|11=|35=D|40=1|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|54=|8=FIX.4.4|43=Y|100=MBTX|59=0|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|553=2453|49=11342|21=1|9=205|55=/GCQ3|10=085|1=30532|114=Y|56=MBT|

Order:610550,59=0|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|8=FIX.4.4|100=MBTX|43=Y|35=D|40=1|54=|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|38=521|11=|34=388|56=MBT|55=/GCQ3|10=085|1=30532|114=Y|9=205|553=2453|49=11342|21=1|

Order:408689,59=0|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|8=FIX.4.4|43=Y|100=MBTX|35=D|40=1|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|54=|38=658|34=388|11=|56=MBT|55=/GCQ3|10=085|114=Y|1=30532|9=205|49=11342|553=2453|21=1|

Order:43899,56=MBT|10=085|55=/GCQ3|114=Y|1=30532|9=205|21=1|49=11342|553=2453|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|59=0|100=MBTX|43=Y|8=FIX.4.4|40=1|35=D|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|54=|11=|34=388|38=531|
```

Comment: Care to tell us what you've tried?

Comment: using awk...

awk -F\| '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/^38=/)if(substr($i,4,length($i))>=100&&substr($i,4,length($i))<=500){print}}' input.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty easy in perl, if you're not tied to using grep.  If the line matches \ or , followed by 38=, place all the characters until the next | in $1.  And then just print lines where $1 is between 100 and 500.

```
$ perl -ne 'if(/[\|,]38=(.*)\|/&&$1>99&&$1<501){print $_}' q
Order:916070,35=D|40=1|54=|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|38=234|34=388|11=|59=0|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|8=FIX.4.4|100=MBTX|43=Y|9=205|553=2453|49=11342|21=1|56=MBT|55=/GCQ3|10=085|1=30532|114=Y|
Order:385327,38=190|34=388|11=|35=D|40=1|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|54=|8=FIX.4.4|43=Y|100=MBTX|59=0|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|553=2453|49=11342|21=1|9=205|55=/GCQ3|10=085|1=30532|114=Y|56=MBT|
$
```

Using grep we don't have > and < operators (as far as I know), look for the same 38= pattern followed by either [1-4][0-9][0-9] (100 thru 499) or 500.

```
$ grep -E '[,|]38=([1-4][0-9][0-9]|500)\|' q
Order:916070,35=D|40=1|54=|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|38=234|34=388|11=|59=0|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|8=FIX.4.4|100=MBTX|43=Y|9=205|553=2453|49=11342|21=1|56=MBT|55=/GCQ3|10=085|1=30532|114=Y|
Order:385327,38=190|34=388|11=|35=D|40=1|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|54=|8=FIX.4.4|43=Y|100=MBTX|59=0|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|553=2453|49=11342|21=1|9=205|55=/GCQ3|10=085|1=30532|114=Y|56=MBT|
$
```

Comment: could you also explain the expression? that would be much appreciated

Comment: Also how can I print just unique values of tag 38 no duplicates and show the count of unique values? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably best to post a new question for that.  Showing what the input would be and what the output would be.

Comment: I can't post any new question from account. It says wait for 1 more day :(